# convert*bat file to .sh file

Tags: file, batch-file

I would like to change the batch file to *.sh file to run in linux?

the *bat file as following:

```
@echo off
rem -----------
rem Use following two lines to input value on command line
rem if "%1"=="" goto NoRunners
rem set N=%1
rem -----------
set N=8

if %N%==0 goto NoRunners

cd W:\MCMC\runner1\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 1
Start "Runner 1" /min runner

if %N%==1 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner2\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 2
Start "Runner 2" /min runner

if %N%==2 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner3\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 3
Start "Runner 3" /min runner

if %N%==3 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner2\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 4
Start "Runner 4" /min runner

if %N%==4 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner3\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 5
Start "Runner 5" /min runner

if %N%==5 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner3\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 6
Start "Runner 6" /min runner

if %N%==6 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner3\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 7
Start "Runner 7" /min runner

if %N%==7 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner3\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 8
Start "Runner 8" /min runner

if %N%==8 goto GoHome

cd W:\MCMC\runner3\MCMC\tracer2D\
Echo Starting Runner 9
Start "Runner 9" /min runner



:GoHome
cd ..\..\..\
goto End

:NoRunners
Echo No Runners started

:End
pause
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far

Comment: Rewrite this batch file in shell script ! There is no automatic routine that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You would literally have to hand translate that entire script. I have had an idea for a while, though, to make a bash implementation of at least the DOS batch language (extensions and Windows specific commands will be a harder one to pull off), but it would take a *lot* of work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sh script to automate this task with sed. Run it in the directory with batch files (backup has .bak extension):

```
#!/bin/sh
files="*.bat"
sed -i.bak "s/%\([^%]\+\)%/\$\1/g" $files #Variables conversion
sed -i "s/%\([0-9]\+\)\b/\$\1/g" $files
sed -i "s/if \+not \+defined \+\([^ ]\+\) /[ -z \"\$\1\" ] \&\& /gI" $files
sed -i "s/if \+defined \+\([^ ]\+\) /[ -n \"\$\1\" ] \&\& /gI" $files
sed -i "s/if \+not \+exist \+\([^ ]\+\) /[ ! -f \$\1 ] \&\& /gI" $files
sed -i "s/if \+exist \+\([^ ]\+\) /[ -f \$\1 ] \&\& /gI" $files
sed -i "s/if \+not \+\([^ ]\+\) /[ ! \1 ] \&\& /gI" $files
sed -i "s/if \([^ ]\+\) /[ \1 ] \&\& /gI" $files
sed -i "s/\\\\/\//gI" $files  #path conversion
sed -i "s/\^|/|/gI" $files #backslashed pipe conversion
sed -i "s/\"==\"/\" == \"/gI" *.bat # == conversion
sed -i "s/\brem /# /gI" $files #comments conversion
sed -i "s/\bnul\b/\/dev\/null/gI" $files # 'nul' conversion
sed -i "s/\bset //gI" $files # 'set' conversion
sed -i "s/\btype /cat /gI" $files # 'type' conversion
sed -i "s/\bfind /grep /gI" $files # 'find' conversion
sed -i "s/\bdel\(ete\)\? /rm /gI" $files # 'del' conversion
```

I published the script here:
https://github.com/meshr-net/helpers/blob/master/bat2sh.sh